# How to generate a unique MD5 Hash value for a Fingerprint Minutiae Extraction features for fast authentication

Tags: python, opencv, uniqueidentifier, fingerprint

I want to implement Fingerprint Verification System in OpenCV and Python but the way I want to do it is as follows:

Enrollment Process:

1. Input Fingerprint
2. Extract Features using Minutiae Extraction
3. Find a Unique Alphanumeric value generated from Minutiae features for 
   this fingerprint
4. Store the Fingerprint Template and the Unique ID (Hash) in the 
   database

Verification Process:

1. Input Fingerprint image
2. Extract Features using Minutiae Extraction
3. Find a Unique Alphanumeric value generated from Minutiae features for 
    this fingerprint
4. Compare this Unique ID (hash) with the one stored in the database

So the major challenge for me is to extract this Unique hash value from the fingerprint features.

Is it possible to generate such a unique ID from fingerprint features?

The base code I'm using is: 
[Here](https://github.com/kjanko/python-fingerprint-recognition)

And the research paper I read for it is:
[Authentication Method Based on Hashes Fingerprint For fast retrieval](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d6e5/7702367fe8aee5b20d2d3310cc1263e13503.pdf)

Note:
Two sets of Minutiae can't absolutely identical when extracted from two different finger prints of the same person. If it matches more than 80% That's a good match.

Small differences in input make large differences in output is a big  problem, but still if the hashes matches above 68% , That's still feasible for my requirement.

The Author of the paper says to find a distance vector and using MD5 over that vector.

```
D = sqrt( (Xi-Xc)^2 + (Yi -Yc)^2 )
```

*Where (xi, yi) is the coordinate of feature and (xc, yc) is the 
coordinate of core point. After determining the
features' distances, the identification numbers is
computed by using the MD5 hash function.*

[Research Paper hashes of fingerprints of same person](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSjkN.jpg)

Comment: As it is currently phrased, your question is too broad. Please focus on one specific question. "Possible to generate hash for minutiae?" is still too broad. Please provide samples and a summary of the structure of the information to hash. Make sure that you provide enough detail to judge whether the general attribute of hashes (small differences in input make large differences in output) are a problem.

Comment: Please state whether two sets of minutiae are absolutely identical when derived from two finger prints of the same person. I know they are designed to be similar (that is their idea after all), but for using hashes they need to be absolutely identical.